# Build Project Tree in CMake

Tags: cmake

I suppose this is so simple that nobody bothers to write it down, but I cannot figure it out. Let's consider a trivial example.

```
ProjectTree
  |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- Library1
  |    |- CMakeLists.txt
  |    |- src
  |    |- include
  |- Library2 # depends on Library1
  |    |- CMakeLists.txt
  |    |- src
  |    |- include
  |- Program1 # depends on Library2 (not directly on Library1)
  |    |- CMakeLists.txt
  |    |- src
  |- Program2 # depends on Library2 (not directly on Library1)
  |    |- CMakeLists.txt
       |- src
```

How do I build this with CMake 3, in larger scale (we have about 20 libraries)? I need to request build of Program1 and have Program1, Library1 and Library2 updated, as they depend on each other. Then to request build of Program2 and not have Library1 and Library2 compiled again. Also, when I change something in Library1, it all dependent targets should detect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`target_link_libraries(Library2 Library1)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) in Library2/CMakeLists.txt and then `target_link_libraries(Program1 Library2)` in Program1/CMakeLists.txt. Library 1 will be automatically linked to Program1 because of the dependency you have described for Library2. You may also need to use [`target_include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) (see the example at the bottom of the doc page) for each of your libraries to describe include directories, which should be "exported" i.e. added to the include directories for the code which *uses* a particular library, not the library itself.

You may also find useful the example at the bottom of the `target_link_libraries` page describing the case when Library1 and Library2 depend on each other and (most of popular) linkers  demand that one of these libraries is to be specified twice in the link command, the first time before the other library and the second time -after the other library.